# How to stop SCons rebuilding all .class files when the java input is generated as the result of another builder?

Tags: java, scons

As part of a reasonably complex cross-platform build I invoke the SCons Java builder. The .java files **are auto-generated from templates*. They contain package information: `package com.example.package;` and are laid out accordingly in directories. `src/com/example/package/MyClass.java`

SConscript:

```
# javaSources is the absolute path to each java file i.e src/com/example/package/MyClass.java
# outputClassesPath is classes/
JavaArtifacts = env.Java(target = outputClassesPath, source = javaSources)
```

The first call to scons correctly builds MyClass.java and puts the output in `classes/com/example/package/MyClass.class`

If I call scons again - with no change - the javac command is run again. Using `scons --debug=explain` I get:

```
scons: building 'classes/MyClass.class' because it doesn't exist
```

This is true - but `classes/com/example/package/MyClass.class` does exist!

This looks like a bug in SCons to me. It seems SCons correctly creates the .class files in the right place, but its first pass doesn't seem to know where this right place is.

**Update**: The Java files are created by a template engine (called using the `env.Command` pattern). The artifacts returned by the template engine test True for `.is_derived()`. This looks like it causes the package directory structure to be ignored by the java emitter, but I can't think why. Maybe I need to create a full builder for the templates,  stop using `Command`, and override the default for `.is_derived()`. Or else I could create a new Java builder (based on the provided one), without this check on the emitter.

Comment: It does indeed seem like a bug. I would recommend reporting it to the SCons developer's list: http://www.scons.org/lists.php#dev

Comment: what is the exact build command executed by Java builder? E.g. if I run `C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\bin\javac.exe -d classes src\com\test\hello.java` it puts `hello.class` right into `classes` folder not in `classes\com\test`...

Comment: @kerim 
`javac -d out/classes -sourcepath src/com/example/package/MyClass.java`

If I add a -verbose I get the output:
`[wrote out/classes/com/com/example/package/MyClass.class]`

Did you add a package to your `hello.java`?

Comment: yep. sorry forgot `package`. Still I have a different(from yours) command executed by scons - `javac.exe -d classes -sourcepath src\com\test src\com\test\hello.java` when I configure builder this way - `env.Java('classes', r'src\com\test\hello.java')`

Comment: you could also try `--debug=tree` option to check the dep tree. could figure something out from it, who knows...

Comment: Rather than reporting it to the developers list, please report it to the users list. The developers list is meant for internal development of SCons. The users list is meant to discuss usage/issues using SCons.

Comment: Please post your SConstruct and/or a simplified version which can replicate the issue.  Otherwise it's very difficult to understand/solve the issue.